# How to proper pass a new text value after login using closure

Tags: swift, closures

I'm new to Swift and I want to know how to pass data using closure after user logged in.

I've already tried to use closure in the way above, but nothing happend. In what moment I'm doing this wrong ?

**func in my ConnectionController.swift**

```swift
    public var trueSometh: Bool = true
    var userSigned: (() -> ())?

    func onSignIn(request : UserRequest, callBack : @escaping (UserResponse) -> Void){

        let parameters  : Parameters =  ["email" : request.email! , "password" : request.password!]
        Alamofire.request(EnumURL.login.path, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseObject {
            (response: DataResponse<UserResponse>)  in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    callBack(response.result.value!)
                    print(response)
                    print( response.value?.user?.displayName! ?? "" )
                    self.userSigned?()
                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    var currentUser = defaults.value(forKey: "currentUser") as? String

                    currentUser = response.value?.user?.displayName!
                    defaults.set(currentUser, forKey: "currentUser")

                    var currentVersion = defaults.value(forKey: "currentVersion") as? Bool
                    if currentVersion == true { 
                        currentVersion = false

                        defaults.set(currentVersion, forKey: "currentVersion") 
                    } else {
                        currentVersion = true

                        defaults.set(currentVersion, forKey: "currentVersion")
                    }
                    UIApplication.drawerVC?.setDrawerState(.opened, animated: true)
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

**In Topbar View**

```swift
    let cc = ConnectionController()
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupUI()
        setupBindings()
        cc.userSigned =  { [weak self] in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self.welcomeLabel.text = self.cc.drawerVC.helloLabel.text
            print (self.welcomeLabel.text!)
            print ("self.welcomeLabel.text!")
            self.topBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        self.topBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: First explain this phrase 
"but nothing happend. In what moment I'm doing this wrong ?"   what you expect to happend and what is happening?

Comment: After I log in welcomeLabel.text remains the same,  cc.userSigned is never used in Topbar. I expected to have a a "Hello 'user' " instead of "Hello" in this case.

Comment: if you are using call back in    onSignIn method then why their is any need of other closure?

Answer (score 0):

Your are not passing anything to your userSigned call back pass any value i.e string json , user response etc in below example i have passed UserResponse object. keep in mind you are doing same work twice firstly using call back in `onSignIn` method and then using signed in closure both can perform same task for you so i would recommend use one either closure block or method call back

```
  public var trueSometh: Bool = true
var userSigned: ((_ userResponse:UserResponse) -> ())?

func onSignIn(request : UserRequest, callBack : @escaping (UserResponse) -> Void){

    let parameters  : Parameters =  ["email" : request.email! , "password" : request.password!]
    Alamofire.request(EnumURL.login.path, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseObject {
        (response: DataResponse<UserResponse>)  in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                callBack(response.result.value!)
                print(response)
                print( response.value?.user?.displayName! ?? "" )
               userSigned?(response.result.value)
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                var currentUser = defaults.value(forKey: "currentUser") as? String

                currentUser = response.value?.user?.displayName!
                defaults.set(currentUser, forKey: "currentUser")

                var currentVersion = defaults.value(forKey: "currentVersion") as? Bool
                if currentVersion == true { 
                    currentVersion = false

                    defaults.set(currentVersion, forKey: "currentVersion") 
                } else {
                    currentVersion = true

                    defaults.set(currentVersion, forKey: "currentVersion")
                }
                UIApplication.drawerVC?.setDrawerState(.opened, animated: true)
            }
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

And in viewController

```
let cc = ConnectionController()
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupUI()
        setupBindings()
        cc.userSigned =  { userResponse in
            guard let response = userResponse else { return }
            self.welcomeLabel.text = response.user?.displayName as? String ?? ""    //if response in json dict
            print (self.welcomeLabel.text!)
            print ("self.welcomeLabel.text!")
            self.topBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        self.topBar.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```